# app.config encryption

Tags: app-config, encryption

I am devoloping an windows application in dot net.It's config file includes sensitive data such as sql pass..So When deploying application i want to give it as encrypted.
I googled arund and found one that Rsiprovider to encrypt the fields.
But encryption is machine specific and needs deploying config file in clear mode and after first run of program ,encryption is succeed on the runnig machine.
Is there a way to deploy config files as encrypted ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Think about it - if you encrypt before shipping you will also have to provide a key somewhere. And then the problem shifts to how to hide that key...

The post-setup encryption is meant to hide the config from prying eyes.

Comment: +1, no problem dealing with that other key you just encrypt it, and so on, turtles all the way down :p

Answer (score 0):

This [link](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/security/encryptstrings.aspx) has helped me make an encrypted config file. The problem with other solutions is that they are machine specific, so if you encrypt the .config, it cannot be de-crypted in another machine (not very feasible when you are deploying the app to many machines)